# passportjs idle/inactivity timeout

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js for node.js/expressjs. Its very good authentication module. Does anyone know if its possible to implement inactivity or idle timeout?

I already have a client side js that monitors idle time and logs out the user after 15 mins of inactivity. But lets say the user closed the browser "tab" then my client side js is useless. Is it possible to setup idle timeout on the server side

FYI - just to be clear I am not looking for session timeout variable. I does not help with inactivity.

Comment: Which session store are you using?

Comment: i am using passport.js. It handles everything.

Comment: The That's almost answering to a question like "Which database are you using?" and you answer "I'm using node.js, it handles everything!". Well passportjs doesn't handle everything. passportjs is in charge of authentication, not storing sessions. The session objects must be stored in your process memory or a database.